# Unable to create GCP Secret Engine with Roleset with BigQuery binding, Error: unsupported resource type: projects/datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-gcp

When I try to create a Vault GCP Secret Engine Roleset on a BigQuery Dataset, it throws `unsupported resource type: projects/datasets` error. I'm stuck on this weird error. What is the root cause?

I can see that in the below page, bigquery datasets can be added to a roleset's binding with the full resource name, but it did not work. I don't know what is wrong or what I'm missing. Any ideas?

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/gcp#roleset-bindings

```
resource "vault_gcp_secret_roleset" "dataset_access_key_test" {
  backend     = vault_gcp_secret_backend.gcp.path
  roleset     = var.roleset_name
  secret_type = "service_account_key"
  project     = var.project_id
  binding {
    # Here I've tried both the self_link attribute of the dataset and the full resource name like below. Neither of them worked.
    resource = "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/${var.project_id}/datasets/${var.dataset_id}"
    roles    = ["roles/bigquery.dataViewer"]
  }
}
```

**Command output below:**

> vault_gcp_secret_roleset.<roleset_name>: Creating...
>
> Error: Error writing GCP Secrets backend roleset
> "gcp/roleset/<roleset_name>": Error making API request.
>
> URL: PUT https:///v1/gcp/roleset/<roleset_name> Code: 400. Errors:
>
> 2 errors occurred: errors from both primary and secondary; primary
> error was invalid resource
> "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/<project_id>/datasets/<dataset_id>":
> unsupported resource type: projects/datasets; secondary errors follow
> invalid resource
> "//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/<project_id>/datasets/<dataset_id>":
> unsupported resource type: projects/datasets

Comment: Are you sure your project id and dataset id are correctly set in the resource link?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it. And also I have another roleset before this one which has a GCS bucket in the binding block (`resource = "buckets/playground-dev"`
). It works fine for the bucket but fails when it comes to the BigQuery dataset.

Comment: It was a version conflict, since the Vault version that we use does not support BigQuery ACL bindings. This error will be fixed after a Vault upgrade!